# Problem with loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

i'm trying to compute "2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^14", using the following program(i'm a newbie and can only compute a exponent by multiply itself a certain times). The result should be 32767, but i ran it and got 270566475, i thought for long but can't figure out why...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i, e, exponent, sum;

   e = 1;
   exponent = 1;
   sum = 1;

   for (i = 1; i <=14; i++)
   {
       for (e = 1; e <= i; e++)
       {
          exponent *= 2;
       }

       sum += exponent;
   }

   printf("%d\n", sum);

   return 0;
}
```

So what's wrong with this??? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your inner loop by itself. It's trying to calculate, for one specific value of `i`, `2^i`.

But `exponent` does not start at `1` every time. So you go into that loop with `exponent` already some very large value.

```
for (i = 1; i <=14; i++)
{
    exponent = 1;
    for (e = 1; e <= i; e++)
    {
        exponent *= 2;
    }

    sum += exponent;
}
```

Now you've reset `exponent` (which, to be clear, isn't the exponent at all but the calculated result) for each new power of 2.

Comment: You don't have to use the inner loop as it can be done with the outer loop only, as answered above by Marcelo.....

Comment: Oh, yes~~ initialization! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the inner loop. Just execute `exponent *= 2` once, directly inside the outer loop. BTW, I think you have to do it *after* the `sum += ...`.

Also, you could start with `sum = 0` and `i = 0`, which is closer to the math you described.

Comment: Yeah!~~~ After you told me this, i really don't know why i did it in that complex way, thankkkkks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have right to create a function it better to do it like this with a recursive function :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int x, int exp) {
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * power(x, exp-1);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
        sum += power(2, i);
    }

    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps.

You just need one loop because each you already have the result of n-1 value. I had correct your code it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i, e, exponent, sum;

    e = 1;
    exponent = 1;
    sum = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
    {
        exponent *= 2;
        sum += exponent;
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Both codes work

Comment: You can reuse this function to do for example 3^3, 4^4 any value you want (x^exp).

Comment: Don't recommend recursion where iteration is called for. (And likewise don't make complex solutions to simple errors.)

Comment: Oh, thank you! but for me stuff like power, argc are symbols that are more mysterious than Latin now, hehe~~ thanks a lot!

Comment: Your are welcome. The argc is automatically generated by the software.

Comment: I didn't saw the comment before. For some people like recursion is faster and easier to set in some cases. And I know it takes place in the memory but for a small operation like this it's nothing.